# Sorting Gantt Bars (vb .net) - simplified

Tags: vb.net

Ok, i can see this question is problematic, so I've attempted to explain it in a simplified way, with more code. I suppose this boils down to list reordering and/or reallocation.

I've inserted some of the code from the app to hopefully help.

As mentioned, any time-range overlaps within the same posIndex needs to have an increment of 1 added to its PosIndex. In addition, an increase to all others below it must move by 1 also. As the code iterates through and finds another overlap that has the same PosIndex (not from one above), it again moves it by one, and all others below it. Those on the same index that are not overlapping must have their PosINdex untouched. Only by overlaps above it should their PosIndex increase by 1, pushing them down.

I hope this explanation helps. I'm really, really stuck with this.

I've left the old post below, if it helps.

```
 Module ttest

    Public Class barAllocations

        Dim lstBars As List(Of barAllocations)
        Public Property barText As String
        Public Property FromTime() As DateTime
        Public Property ToTime() As DateTime
        Public Property PosIndex() As Integer

        Public Sub addAlloBar(ByVal setBarText As String, ByVal FromTime As DateTime, ToTime As DateTime, PosIndex As Integer)

            Dim alloBar As New barAllocations
            alloBar.barText = setBarText
            alloBar.FromTime = FromTime
            alloBar.ToTime = ToTime
            alloBar.PosIndex = PosIndex

            lstBars.Add(alloBar)

        End Sub

        Public Sub sortList()
            Dim prevIndex As Integer
            Dim prevFromDT As DateTime
            Dim prevToDT As DateTime

            For Each bar As barAllocations In lstBars

                If bar.ToTime > prevFromDT And bar.FromTime < prevToDT And bar.PosIndex = prevIndex Then

                    bar.PosIndex += 1

                    For Each bars As barAllocations In lstBars

                        If bar.PosIndex > prevIndex Then bars.PosIndex += 1

                    Next

                End If

                prevFromDT = bar.FromTime
                prevToDT = bar.ToTime
                prevIndex = bar.PosIndex

            Next

        End Sub

    End Class


    Private Sub barAdd()

        Dim startDT As DateTime = Now().AddHours(-48)
        Dim endDT As DateTime = startDT.AddHours(12)

        Dim allogrid As New barAllocations

        allogrid.addAlloBar("test1", startDT, endDT, 0)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test2", startDT, endDT, 0)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test3", startDT.AddHours(12), endDT.AddHours(12), 0)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test4", startDT.AddHours(24), endDT.AddHours(24), 0)

        allogrid.addAlloBar("test5", startDT.AddHours(5), endDT.AddHours(5), 5)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test6", startDT.AddHours(2), endDT.AddHours(2), 5)

        allogrid.addAlloBar("test7", startDT.AddHours(1), endDT.AddHours(1), 6)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test8", startDT.AddHours(5), endDT.AddHours(5), 6)

        allogrid.addAlloBar("test9", startDT.AddHours(7), endDT.AddHours(7), 7)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test10", startDT.AddHours(8), endDT.AddHours(8), 7)

        allogrid.addAlloBar("test11", startDT.AddHours(10), endDT.AddHours(10), 8)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test12", startDT.AddHours(1), endDT.AddHours(1), 8)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test13", startDT.AddHours(22), endDT.AddHours(34), 8)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test14", startDT.AddHours(20), endDT.AddHours(32), 8)

        allogrid.addAlloBar("test15", startDT.AddHours(6), endDT.AddHours(6), 9)
        allogrid.addAlloBar("test16", startDT.AddHours(11), endDT.AddHours(11), 9)

        allogrid.sortList()

    End Sub


End Module
```

////////////////OLD POST/////////////////

I am in the middle of creating a booking app, using a Gantt view to visualize bookings. I draw rectangles where the bookings are to take place based on a date range.

The problem I am having is sorting overlaps. There can be two bookings for the same bed at the same time. What I am trying to do is if there is an overlap, move the bar down one space, but also move all other bars by one space also (the grid and bed row lines will be adjusted at a later point, widening them, to incorporate 2 bars at once).

The bars are placed by assigning a PosIndex, so row 1 is PosIndex 0.

I've been really struggling with this for several days now to no avail.

I thought about using rectangles for intersection detection, which works well, but I'm not able to sort the bars properly. As you can see from the picture, there are overlaps that have not been separated and I have no clue how to do it.

Sorry if my explanation is vague, so please ask for more info if required.

Here's the code i've been working on:

```
  Dim lst As List(Of barAllocation) = lstBars

    Dim prevIndex As Integer
    Dim prevRec As Rectangle
    Dim msg As String = ""

    lst = lst.OrderBy(Function(x) x.PosIndex).ThenBy(Function(y) y.FromTime).ToList

    For Each bar In lst

        Dim tsDate As TimeSpan = bar.ToTime - bar.FromTime
        Dim recstart As Integer = bar.ToTime.Month & bar.ToTime.Day & bar.ToTime.Hour & bar.ToTime.Minute

        Dim barRec As New Rectangle(recstart, bar.PosIndex * 10, tsDate.TotalMinutes, 10)

        If prevRec.IntersectsWith(barRec) Then
            If prevIndex = bar.PosIndex Then
                If bar.PosIndex = 0 Then
                    bar.PosIndex += 1
                    barChanged = bar.PosIndex
                Else
                    barChanged = bar.PosIndex
                    bar.PosIndex += 1
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If bar.PosIndex > barChanged Then bar.PosIndex += 1

        prevRec = barRec
        prevIndex = bar.PosIndex
```

[Example of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzND8.png)

Comment: cyberblitz, it's difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve. However, I would suggest it is better to do your sorting before rendering rather than trying to move things around during the render. It would be better to improve your lst.OrderBy logic.

Comment: Appreciate the difficulty with understanding this, it's a bit complicated to convey.However, I am trying to reorder before rendering - I am just using rectangles here to detect overlaps but I'm not actually rendering them until much later. All I'm trying to do is detect overlaps; if there is an overlap, move the detected overlap by 1 row down, however, doing so means all others below the moved overlap should move by one also. If another Overlap is detected further down, move that one and all others below again. Sorry, if it doesn't make much sense. All I'm trying to do is separate the overlaps

Comment: OK - how about enhancing your barAllocation class to include a "hasOverlap" property and then add it to the sort with another ThenBy? So in step 1 you would loop your barAllocation list and determine the hasOverlap using Linq. Overlaps are typically detected using where (a.TimeTo < b.TimeFrom and a.TimeFrom > b.TimeTo) type logic

Comment: Yes, i have tried that. But i had trouble moving all the other bars down.

Comment: Not really anything like an answer and applaud what you’ve got so far but just thought worth mentioning, there are plenty of 3rd party scheduling tools and controls available, some paid, some not.  Does all the heavy lifting and saves you reinventing the wheel

Comment: I've been searching for quite a while for these tools, and i prefer not to pay for them, and haven't found any that fits the bill

Comment: Cyberblitz - my suggestion is out of first-hand experience, having written several systems with collision detection and scheduling in the past. I know it works. The overlap logic will tell you when you have overlapping items. The only decision left to make is how to prioritise them, and storing that as a secondary order on your object for your final sort query. It makes little difference whether you do it in SQL or using linq, the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for you. The principle is clear, you just need to port it to winforms and render it differently if you need to there.

[image: Proof the code below works]

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Class Booking
        Public Property BookingUID As Guid
        Public Property Bedroom As String
        Public Property BookingName As String
        Public Property DateFrom As Date
        Public Property DateTo As Date
        Public Property HasClash As Boolean = False
        Public Sub New(Bedroom As String, BookingName As String, DateFrom As Date, DateTo As Date)
            BookingUID = Guid.NewGuid
            Me.Bedroom = Bedroom
            Me.BookingName = BookingName
            Me.DateFrom = DateFrom
            Me.DateTo = DateTo
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Bookings As List(Of Booking) = New List(Of Booking)

    Private Sub SortBookings()
        ' Simple sort
        Bookings = (From x In Bookings Select x Order By x.DateFrom, x.DateTo).ToList
        ' Check for clashes (will force booking onto a new line in the chart
        For Each Booking In Bookings
            If (From x In Bookings Where x.DateFrom < Booking.DateTo And x.DateTo > Booking.DateFrom And x.Bedroom = Booking.Bedroom And x.BookingUID <> Booking.BookingUID).Any Then
                Booking.HasClash = True
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RenderBookings()
        Dim s As New StringBuilder
        Dim TotalDays As Integer = 0
        ' get a unique list of bedrooms
        Dim Beds = (From x In Bookings Select x.Bedroom Distinct).OrderBy(Function(b) b)
        Dim MinDate = (From x In Bookings Select x.DateFrom).Min
        Dim MaxDate = (From x In Bookings Select x.DateTo).Max
        s.AppendLine("<table style=""border:solid 1px black;"" cellpadding=""2"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""1"">")
        ' header rows
        s.AppendLine("<tr><td rowspan=""2"">Bedroom</td>")
        Dim Day, Hour As Integer
        For Day = 0 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, MinDate, MaxDate) + 1
            s.AppendLine("<td colspan=""24"" style=""text-align:center;"">" & MinDate.Date.AddDays(Day).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "</td>")
            TotalDays += 1
        Next
        s.AppendLine("</tr><tr>")
        For Day = 0 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, MinDate, MaxDate) + 1
            For Hour = 0 To 23
                s.AppendLine("<td style=""text-align:center;"">" & Hour.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0") & "</td>")
            Next
        Next
        s.AppendLine("</tr>")
        ' Loop bedrooms
        For Each Bed In Beds
            s.AppendLine("<tr style=""height:30px;""><td>" & Bed & "</td><td style=""position:relative;"" colspan=""" & TotalDays * 24 & """>")
            Dim BedBookings = (From x In Bookings Where x.Bedroom = Bed Select x Order By x.DateFrom)
            Dim InsertRows As String = ""
            Dim First As Boolean = True
            ' Loop bookings for each bedroom
            For Each Booking In BedBookings
                ' divide 100 % by the time period in minutes we're trying to cover
                Dim Scale As Decimal = (100 / (TotalDays * 24 * 60)) ' 100% / total minutes in the row
                ' How many whole days are there between this booking and our MinDate.Date?
                Dim OffsetDays As Integer = Math.Floor((Booking.DateFrom.Date - MinDate.Date).TotalDays)
                ' Calculate the left %
                Dim Left As Decimal = ((OffsetDays * 24 * 60) + (Booking.DateFrom - Booking.DateFrom.Date).TotalMinutes) * Scale
                ' Calculate the witdht %
                Dim Width As Decimal = (Booking.DateTo - Booking.DateFrom).TotalMinutes * Scale
                ' Get our Bar HTML
                Dim Bar As String = "<div style=""overflow:hidden;position:absolute;border:solid 1px red;background-color:navy;color:#fff;top:3px;width:" & Width & "%;left:" & Left & "%"" title=""" & Booking.DateFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") & " - " & Booking.DateTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") & " - " & Booking.Bedroom & """>" & Booking.BookingName & "</div>"
                If Booking.HasClash And Not First Then
                    ' We need an insert row here because it's a clash for the same room
                    InsertRows &= "<tr style=""height:30px;""><td></td><td style=""position:relative;"" colspan=""" & TotalDays * 24 & """>"
                    InsertRows &= Bar
                    InsertRows &= "</tr>"
                Else
                    ' Add to this row
                    s.AppendLine(Bar)
                End If
                First = False
            Next
            s.AppendLine("</td></tr>{INSERTROWS}")
            ' Insert our clashing rows
            s = s.Replace("{INSERTROWS}", InsertRows)
        Next
        s.AppendLine("</table>")
        lit_Bars.Text = s.ToString
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' CREATE SOME FAKE BOOKINGS
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 01", "Mr Jones", Date.Today.AddHours(9), Date.Today.AddHours(15)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 02", "Mr & Mrs Williams", Date.Today.AddHours(8), Date.Today.AddHours(20)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 03", "Mrs Ave", Date.Today.AddHours(10), Date.Today.AddHours(17)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 04", "Mr Aubury", Date.Today.AddHours(12), Date.Today.AddHours(22)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 05", "Mr King", Date.Today.AddHours(14), Date.Today.AddHours(20)))
        ' Clashes here
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 06", "Miss Uber", Date.Today.AddHours(7), Date.Today.AddHours(13)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 06", "Dr Jones", Date.Today.AddHours(6), Date.Today.AddHours(10)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 06", "Mr Davis", Date.Today.AddHours(9), Date.Today.AddHours(30)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 07", "Miss Davies", Date.Today.AddHours(8), Date.Today.AddHours(12)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 08", "Mrs Amber", Date.Today.AddHours(6), Date.Today.AddHours(14)))
        ' Clashes here
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 09", "Mr & Mrs Red", Date.Today.AddHours(10), Date.Today.AddHours(17)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 09", "Mr Green", Date.Today.AddHours(2), Date.Today.AddHours(16)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 09", "Mrs Brown", Date.Today.AddHours(7), Date.Today.AddHours(40)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 10", "Mr Orange", Date.Today.AddHours(14), Date.Today.AddHours(19)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 10", "Miss Pink", Date.Today.AddHours(26), Date.Today.AddHours(40)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 11", "Miss Nathan", Date.Today.AddHours(13), Date.Today.AddHours(28)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 12", "Mr Black", Date.Today.AddHours(7), Date.Today.AddHours(18)))

        SortBookings()
        RenderBookings()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll look at this more closely tomorrow. I can't use WinForms as I'm working on app that does not contain any WinForms at all. As for rendering, I have this part working very well (with H&V scroll bars too), it's only the Y position I'm struggling with, especially when there are overlaps. I just need to sort the list, but it seems LINQ may well be the answer here

Comment: I should be clear, the example I provided to you is HTML. I have provided you with fully working code that does what you want. If you need to get the "rectangles" (bookings) into a list of some kind for rendering as something other than HTML then modify my code to write objects to a list of rooms instead of directly as HTML. Your "room" object would need to contain a sub-list of booking objects. Store HasClash bookings for adding to the list after adding non-clashing. You're not going to get any better help on here than someone taking the time to write you fully working code from scratch.

Comment: This is great code, thank you. Yea, I'll have a closer look today, however, i couldn't see anywhere in the code on how to deal with vacant beds. I'm not used to this type code so i may have missed it. I'm not expecting anyone to write the code for me, only to help me understand the logic i need to apply here. My main focus is to try and reassign the PosIndex when there are Overlaps detected. Let you know how get on, thanks

Comment: @cyberblitz - if you want to handle vacant beds (assuming you are using an SQL database) I would suggest having beds as the SQL query primary table, and left outer join onto the bookings table. That way, when you are building your list of bookings you can detect a row with no dates (there will be one for each bed with no bookings) and inject an item into your list with booking dates from/to set to the first day/time you want to show in your chart.  You then know not to render a rectangle for that item, but still show the room.

Comment: Yea, I think I'll have to resort to doing just that, however, I like solving problems and wish I could solve this one without resolving to SQL. Half a solve is a win, right?? :)

Comment: @cyberblitz horses for courses. Sometimes SQL can save you hours of coding and make things super fast and efficient. Sometimes it better to do things in code. Best not to shy away from SQL if it's the right tool for the job. You could just as easily do this in code by scanning your "beds" list for each bed you expect to find, and adding a dummy bed (as above) for any that are missing. Linq will make this fast and efficient for you.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with LINQ but I am comfortable with SQL. But since seeing LINQ in your code, I didn't realise how powerful it can be but does seem very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i come up with a sort of solution, but it just seems very unnecessary coding. It doesn't deal with more than 2 entries on the same index at all, but i shouldn't need anymore than 2 assigned to each index

if anyone has any better ideas, love to here it.

```vb
For Each bar In lst       
    If prevFromDT < bar.ToTime And prevToDT > bar.FromTime And prevIndex = bar.PosIndex Then
        bar.overLap = True
    End If
next

For Each tsk In lst
    If tsk.overLap Then
        For Each tsk1 In lst
            If tsk1.PosIndex > tsk.PosIndex Then tsk1.PosIndex += 1
        Next
    End If
Next
    
For Each tsk In lst
    If tsk.overLap Then
        tsk.PosIndex += 1
    End If
Next
```