# Sorting conundrum (try at your peril) <VB .NET>

Tags: vb.net

Ok, I have been attempting this problem for 2 solid weeks now and have to admit it's driving me insane.

Here is the data:

```
RowText AlloIndex   PosIndex    FromTime            ToTime        OverLap
test1      0           0    21/06/2022 14:42    22/06/2022 2:43     0
test2      0           0    21/06/2022 14:42    22/06/2022 2:43     1
test3      0           0    22/06/2022 2:42     22/06/2022 14:43    0
test4      0           0    22/06/2022 14:42    23/06/2022 2:43     0
test5      5           5    21/06/2022 19:42    22/06/2022 7:43     0
test6      6           6    21/06/2022 16:42    22/06/2022 4:43     0
test7      7           7    21/06/2022 15:42    22/06/2022 3:43     0
test8      7           7    21/06/2022 19:42    22/06/2022 7:43     1
test9      8           8    21/06/2022 21:42    22/06/2022 9:43     0
test10     8           8    21/06/2022 22:42    22/06/2022 10:43    1
test11     9           9    22/06/2022 0:42     22/06/2022 12:43    0
test12     9           9    21/06/2022 15:42    22/06/2022 3:43     1
test13     9           9    22/06/2022 12:42    23/06/2022 12:43    1
test14     9           9    22/06/2022 10:42    23/06/2022 10:43    1
test15    10          10    21/06/2022 20:42    22/06/2022 8:43     0
test16    10          10    22/06/2022 1:42     22/06/2022 13:43    1
```

What I am attempting to do is, if there is a time overlap in the same **AlloIndex** group, increase the **PosIndex** of the overlaps by 1 (those identified as an overlap are those greater in time in the same **AlloInndex** group that overlap. I have already highlighted these by the **Overlap** column).

However, this is the tricky part, if an overlap increases the **PosIndex** by 1, all other rows with **PosIndex** values greater than the overlap **PosIndex** are also increased by 1. Example: **PosIndex** 0 has an overlap, so all **PosIndex** greater than 0 also have to increase by 1, in a sense moving them down the rank. **PosIdex** 9, in particular, is very tricky, because you have 4 entries, and 3 overlaps. So you have to increase the **PosIndex** of each overlapped entry by 1 (leaving the 1st entry in the group alone), but also any **PosIndex** greater also needs to increase by 1. Hope this makes sense.

I have tried **FOR LOOPS**, **LINQ**, and **lambda** to no avail...

This is the closest I have come to solving this, but it doesn't work when there are more than 2 overlaps in the same **AlloIndex** Group.

```
For Each bar In lst       

    If prevFromDT < bar.ToTime 
      And prevToDT > bar.FromTime 
      And prevIndex = bar.PosIndex Then

        bar.overLap = True

    End If

next

    For Each tsk In lst

        If tsk.overLap Then

            For Each tsk1 In lst

                If tsk1.PosIndex > tsk.PosIndex Then 
                    tsk1.PosIndex += 1

                Next

        End If

    Next

    For Each tsk In lst

        If tsk.overLap Then

            tsk.PosIndex += 1

        End If

    Next
```

The resulting data should look like this:

```
RowText AlloIndex   PosIndex    FromTime           ToTime        OverLap
test1     0            0      21/06/2022 14:42  22/06/2022 2:43    0
test2     0            1      21/06/2022 14:42  22/06/2022 2:43    1
test3     0            0      22/06/2022 2:42   22/06/2022 14:43   0
test4     0            0      22/06/2022 14:42  23/06/2022 2:43    0
test5     5            6      21/06/2022 19:42  22/06/2022 7:43    0
test6     6            7      21/06/2022 16:42  22/06/2022 4:43    0
test7     7            8      21/06/2022 15:42  22/06/2022 3:43    0
test8     7            9      21/06/2022 19:42  22/06/2022 7:43    1
test9     8           10      21/06/2022 21:42  22/06/2022 9:43    0
test10    8           11      21/06/2022 22:42  22/06/2022 10:43   1
test11    9           12      22/06/2022 0:42   22/06/2022 12:43   0
test12    9           13      21/06/2022 15:42  22/06/2022 3:43    1
test13    9           14      22/06/2022 12:42  23/06/2022 12:43   1
test14    9           15      22/06/2022 10:42  23/06/2022 10:43   1
test15    10          16      21/06/2022 20:42  22/06/2022 8:43    0
test16    10          17      22/06/2022 1:42   22/06/2022 13:43   1
```

Comment: Is the shown data before any processing? Can you show what the data should look like after you have performed a successful run?

Comment: I have added this. Sorry, it was an oversight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting Gantt Bars (vb .net) - simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684771/sorting-gantt-bars-vb-net-simplified)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have been working on this solidly for two weeks and I can't solve it. Yes, it is the same problem, but I'm simply desperate at this point to try and ask the question from a different approach.

Comment: @cyberblitz i gave you fully working code. If you look at the screenshot and data in the code, you can see that it did exactly what you needed. Because I am waiting for other people I have an unusual quiet day in my dev-schedule. I will try to help. How do these columns (above) relate to rooms and bookings, and how are you distinguishing between a main row and a sub row (caused by an overlap)?

Comment: I apologise and I am grateful for your help but I could not integrate your code without a complete rewrite of some modules. You see, I have already managed all the rendering modules, and the bar rendering is particularly reliant on the PosIndex for Y positioning. All the rest works fine. The reason I seem hell-bent on this module working is that I require the sorting module when the user adds a new entry, or a new bar, and the sort module will resort the bars ready to save to the SQL database.

Comment: @Fawlty Also, in answer to your questions, Alloindex is the actual room space (for grouping), and the PosIndex is for Y positioning the bar. The main row is the earliest DateTime in the AlloIndex group, if there is an Overlap, the later ones in the group are considered Overlaps (maybe not the best approach, I know), unless they are not. If they are not an Overlap, they should be positioned at the top of their group, next to any other bars, if there are any. Does this make sense?

Comment: I will write the code for you now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. Not an elegant solution but it works as I wanted:

```
   Private Sub sortGroup(inAlloINdex As Integer)

        Dim msg As String
        Dim groplist = From x In lstBars Order By x.FromTime Where x.AllocationIndex = inAlloINdex And x.overLap = True
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim prevStaff As String = ""

        ' Apply sequential index to overlaps in each bed group
        For Each bar In groplist

            bar.BedOverLapIndex += i
            i += 1

        Next

        ' Determines time ranges (bars) that don't interest/overlap and resets those identified to 0, more found adds 1 in same bed group. This allows bars to orgnise and packs together
        For Each bar In groplist

            For Each bars In groplist

                If (bar.ToTime <= bars.FromTime) And prevStaff <> bar.BarText Then

                    bars.BedOverLapIndex = j

                    prevStaff = bar.BarText

                    j += 1

                End If

            Next

        Next

        i = 0

        ' this was needed to ensure there were no BedOverLapIndex gaps

        For Each tst In groplist.OrderBy(Function(y) y.BedOverLapIndex)

            '  msg &= tst.BarText & " | " & tst.AllocationIndex & " | " & tst.PosIndex & " | " & tst.overLap & " | " & tst.BedOverLapIndex & vbCrLf


            If tst.BedOverLapIndex <> (i + 1) And tst.BedOverLapIndex <> i Then tst.BedOverLapIndex -= 1

            i = tst.BedOverLapIndex

        Next


        '  MsgBox(msg)

    End Sub

    Private Sub addBedOverLapIndex()

        Dim msg As String = ""

        Dim sortGroupLst As New List(Of barAllocation)

        ' Apply true to each entry indentified as a time overalp

        For Each bar In lstBars.OrderBy(Function(x) x.AllocationIndex).ThenBy(Function(x) x.FromTime)

            If (From x In lstBars Where x.FromTime < bar.ToTime And x.ToTime > bar.FromTime And x.PosIndex = bar.PosIndex And x.BookingUID <> bar.BookingUID).Any Then bar.overLap = True

        Next

        'Loop to sort each bed group and apply indecies for Y positioning 
        Dim bars = (From x In lstBars Order By x.AllocationIndex Select x.AllocationIndex).Distinct

        For Each bar In bars

            sortGroup(bar)

        Next

    End Sub



    Public Sub sortbars()

        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim first As Boolean = True
        '   Dim msg As String
        Dim prevOverLapIx As Integer
        Dim prevPosIx As Integer
        Dim prevAlloIx As Integer

        addBedOverLapIndex()

        Dim RemoveFirstOverlap = lstBars.Where(Function(ol1) ol1.overLap = True).GroupBy(Function(x) x.PosIndex, Function(key, g) g.OrderBy(Function(e) e.FromTime).FirstOrDefault).ToList()


        lstBars = (From x In lstBars Select x Order By x.AllocationIndex, x.BedOverLapIndex).ToList

        'Update PosIndex for Y Positioning
        For Each s In lstBars

            s.PosIndex += j

            'This ensures the first in each bed group is not affected
            If s.BedOverLapIndex > 0 Then

                j += 1
                If prevOverLapIx <> s.BedOverLapIndex Then s.PosIndex += 1

            End If

            'Required to ensure no gaps in PosIndex in each Bed Group AND no gaps with next AlloIndex 
            If (s.PosIndex - prevPosIx) > 1 And (prevAlloIx = s.AllocationIndex OrElse (prevAlloIx + 1) = s.AllocationIndex) Then s.PosIndex -= 1

            prevPosIx = s.PosIndex
            prevOverLapIx = s.BedOverLapIndex
            prevAlloIx = s.AllocationIndex

            ' msg &= s.BarText & " | " & s.AllocationIndex & " | " & s.PosIndex & " | " & s.overLap & " | " & s.BedOverLapIndex & vbCrLf

        Next

        ' Adds Additional Rows if Overlap bars are detected

        For Each bar In lstBars

            If prevAlloIx = bar.AllocationIndex And prevOverLapIx <> bar.BedOverLapIndex Then insertRowNameSpaces(bar.RowTxt, bar.PosIndex)

            prevOverLapIx = bar.BedOverLapIndex
            prevAlloIx = bar.AllocationIndex

        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... The `RenderBookings()` code is irrelevant - it's just to show that the sorted data is correct and matches what it should look like. `SortBookings()` is what you need to look at.

[image: Before and After sort proof]

[image: Visual proof (for comparison)]

ASPX code...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="BookingSorting.aspx.vb" Inherits="Scrap.BookingSorting" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h3>Before</h3>
            <asp:GridView ID="gv_Before" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>
            <h3>After</h3>
            <asp:GridView ID="gv_After" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>
            <h3>Proof</h3>
            <asp:Literal ID="lit_Bars" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

VB.NET Code

```
Public Class BookingSorting
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Class Booking
        Public Property BookingUID As Guid
        Public Property Bedroom As String ' AlloIndex
        Public Property PosIndex As Integer
        Public Property BookingName As String
        Public Property DateFrom As Date
        Public Property DateTo As Date
        Public Property HasClash As Boolean = False
        Public Sub New(Bedroom As String, BookingName As String, DateFrom As Date, DateTo As Date)
            BookingUID = Guid.NewGuid
            Me.Bedroom = Bedroom
            Me.BookingName = BookingName
            Me.DateFrom = DateFrom
            Me.DateTo = DateTo
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Bookings As List(Of Booking) = New List(Of Booking)

    Private Sub SortBookings()
        ' Simple sort
        Bookings = (From x In Bookings Select x Order By x.DateFrom, x.DateTo).ToList
        ' Check for clashes (will force booking onto a new line in the chart
        For Each Booking In Bookings
            If (From x In Bookings Where x.DateFrom < Booking.DateTo And x.DateTo > Booking.DateFrom And x.Bedroom = Booking.Bedroom And x.BookingUID <> Booking.BookingUID).Any Then
                Booking.HasClash = True
            End If
        Next
        ' Somewhere to write the list as we sort it
        Dim SortedBookings As List(Of Booking) = New List(Of Booking)

        ' get a unique list of bedrooms
        Dim Beds = (From x In Bookings Select x.Bedroom Distinct).OrderBy(Function(b) b)

        ' Loop bedrooms
        For Each Bed In Beds
            Dim BedBookings = (From x In Bookings Where x.Bedroom = Bed Select x Order By x.DateFrom)
            Dim InsertBookings As New List(Of Booking)
            Dim First As Boolean = True
            ' Loop bookings for each bedroom
            For Each Booking In BedBookings
                If Booking.HasClash And Not First Then
                    Booking.PosIndex = InsertBookings.Count + 1
                    InsertBookings.Add(Booking)
                Else
                    ' Add to this row
                    Booking.PosIndex = 0
                    SortedBookings.Add(Booking)
                End If
                First = False
            Next
            SortedBookings.AddRange(InsertBookings)
        Next
        Bookings = SortedBookings
    End Sub

    Private Sub Test()
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 06", "Miss Uber", Date.Today.AddHours(7), Date.Today.AddHours(13)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 01", "Mr Jones", Date.Today.AddHours(9), Date.Today.AddHours(15)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 03", "Mrs Ave", Date.Today.AddHours(10), Date.Today.AddHours(17)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 04", "Mr Aubury", Date.Today.AddHours(12), Date.Today.AddHours(22)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 10", "Mr Orange", Date.Today.AddHours(14), Date.Today.AddHours(19)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 12", "Mr Black", Date.Today.AddHours(7), Date.Today.AddHours(18)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 05", "Mr King", Date.Today.AddHours(14), Date.Today.AddHours(20)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 08", "Mrs Amber", Date.Today.AddHours(6), Date.Today.AddHours(14)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 09", "Mr & Mrs Red", Date.Today.AddHours(10), Date.Today.AddHours(17)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 06", "Dr Jones", Date.Today.AddHours(6), Date.Today.AddHours(10)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 02", "Mr & Mrs Williams", Date.Today.AddHours(8), Date.Today.AddHours(20)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 09", "Mrs Brown", Date.Today.AddHours(7), Date.Today.AddHours(40)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 06", "Mr Davis", Date.Today.AddHours(9), Date.Today.AddHours(30)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 07", "Miss Davies", Date.Today.AddHours(8), Date.Today.AddHours(12)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 10", "Miss Pink", Date.Today.AddHours(26), Date.Today.AddHours(40)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 11", "Miss Nathan", Date.Today.AddHours(13), Date.Today.AddHours(28)))
        Bookings.Add(New Booking("Bedroom 09", "Mr Green", Date.Today.AddHours(2), Date.Today.AddHours(16)))
        gv_Before.DataSource = Bookings
        gv_Before.DataBind()
        SortBookings()
        gv_After.DataSource = Bookings
        gv_After.DataBind()
        RenderBookings()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RenderBookings()
        Dim s As New StringBuilder
        Dim TotalDays As Integer = 0
        ' get a unique list of bedrooms
        Dim Beds = (From x In Bookings Select x.Bedroom Distinct).OrderBy(Function(b) b)
        Dim MinDate = (From x In Bookings Select x.DateFrom).Min
        Dim MaxDate = (From x In Bookings Select x.DateTo).Max
        s.AppendLine("<table style=""border:solid 1px black;"" cellpadding=""2"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""1"">")
        ' header rows
        s.AppendLine("<tr><td rowspan=""2"">Bedroom</td>")
        Dim Day, Hour As Integer
        For Day = 0 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, MinDate, MaxDate) + 1
            s.AppendLine("<td colspan=""24"" style=""text-align:center;"">" & MinDate.Date.AddDays(Day).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "</td>")
            TotalDays += 1
        Next
        s.AppendLine("</tr><tr>")
        For Day = 0 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, MinDate, MaxDate) + 1
            For Hour = 0 To 23
                s.AppendLine("<td style=""text-align:center;"">" & Hour.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0") & "</td>")
            Next
        Next
        s.AppendLine("</tr>")
        ' Loop bedrooms
        For Each Bed In Beds
            s.AppendLine("<tr style=""height:30px;""><td>" & Bed & "</td><td style=""position:relative;"" colspan=""" & TotalDays * 24 & """>")
            Dim BedBookings = (From x In Bookings Where x.Bedroom = Bed Select x)
            Dim InsertRows As String = ""
            Dim First As Boolean = True
            ' Loop bookings for each bedroom
            For Each Booking In BedBookings
                ' divide 100 % by the time period in minutes we're trying to cover
                Dim Scale As Decimal = (100 / (TotalDays * 24 * 60)) ' 100% / total minutes in the row
                ' How many whole days are there between this booking and our MinDate.Date?
                Dim OffsetDays As Integer = Math.Floor((Booking.DateFrom.Date - MinDate.Date).TotalDays)
                ' Calculate the left %
                Dim Left As Decimal = ((OffsetDays * 24 * 60) + (Booking.DateFrom - Booking.DateFrom.Date).TotalMinutes) * Scale
                ' Calculate the width %
                Dim Width As Decimal = (Booking.DateTo - Booking.DateFrom).TotalMinutes * Scale
                ' Get our Bar HTML
                Dim Bar As String = "<div style=""overflow:hidden;position:absolute;border:solid 1px red;background-color:navy;color:#fff;top:3px;width:" & Width & "%;left:" & Left & "%"" title=""" & Booking.DateFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") & " - " & Booking.DateTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") & " - " & Booking.Bedroom & """>" & Booking.BookingName & "</div>"
                If Booking.HasClash And Not First Then
                    ' We need an insert row here because it's a clash for the same room
                    InsertRows &= "<tr style=""height:30px;""><td></td><td style=""position:relative;"" colspan=""" & TotalDays * 24 & """>"
                    InsertRows &= Bar
                    InsertRows &= "</tr>"
                Else
                    ' Add to this row
                    s.AppendLine(Bar)
                End If
                First = False
            Next
            s.AppendLine("</td></tr>{INSERTROWS}")
            ' Insert our clashing rows
            s = s.Replace("{INSERTROWS}", InsertRows)
        Next
        s.AppendLine("</table>")
        lit_Bars.Text = s.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub BookingSorting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Test()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, however, the code you provided only applies an index to each overlap grouping, to each room, and does not increase the PosIndex greater than the Overlapped PosIndex when an Overlap occurs.  This is where I'm really stuck on. Coincidentally, yesterday, while waiting, i managed to write code that did exactly the same thing, with very similar code to yours. I'm getting the impression I'm never going to solve this

Comment: I really don't understand why you need it to do any more than it's already doing? I can render a perfectly good chart from the data that sort generates. Can you show me a picture of how your chart needs to differ from the one I've drawn?

Comment: The problem is, although the code you provided is excellent, it's primarily for WinForms, which I'm not using. It does not account for both bars jumping to the next row, because of overlap, AND if there are bookings later on that need to stay on the same line. So basically, if there are earlier bookings that overlap and there are later bookings that do not overlap, they all need to align and position correctly. this code does not seem to do that. But, I wouldn't be surprised if i were wrong with this, as I'm not able to test your code in its entirety, as I have no idea how WinForms work.

Comment: and have very little experience with using HTML..

Answer (score 0):

I think i've solved it. I thank @fawlty for guiding me onto Linq/Lambda.  Here is the code. Its a bit messy, but it works.

```
  Private Sub addBedOverLapIndex()

        Dim i As Integer            
        Dim first As Boolean = True

        For Each bar In lstBars

            If (From x In lstBars Where x.FromTime < bar.ToTime And x.ToTime > bar.FromTime And x.PosIndex = bar.PosIndex And x.BookingUID <> bar.BookingUID).Any Then bar.overLap = True
            If bar.overLap Then
                Dim test = From x In lstBars Where x.AllocationIndex = bar.AllocationIndex And bar.overLap = True And x.overLap = True
                If test.Count > 1 Then
                    first = True
                    i = 1
                    For Each all In test
                        If Not first Then
                            all.BedOverLapIndex = i
                            i += 1
                        End If
                        first = False
                    Next
                End If
            End If
         

        Next

    End Sub



    Public Sub sortbars()

        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim first As Boolean = True

        addBedOverLapIndex()
        Dim RemoveFirstOverlap = lstBars.Where(Function(ol1) ol1.overLap = True).GroupBy(Function(x) x.PosIndex, Function(key, g) g.OrderBy(Function(e) e.PosIndex).FirstOrDefault).ToList()

        For Each tst In RemoveFirstOverlap
            tst.overLap = False
        Next

        lstBars = (From x In lstBars Select x Order By x.AllocationIndex, x.BedOverLapIndex).ToList


        For Each s In lstBars

            If s.overLap Then j += 1

            If Not first Then s.PosIndex += j

            first = False

        Next
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. I would be thankful if you would mark my Answer as correct, because it does generate a chart and sorts the data correctly. I think you're doing something really funky because of the way you coded your rendering algorithm.

Comment: The rendering is handled by two methods, one for horizontal lines and one for vertical lines which are influenced by both H & V scroll bars. Not only this but the dates on the top are also rendered by the vertical method. The bars are rendered by another method, which is influenced by the PosIndex (wish I could paste the entire code so you could see).

Comment: Thank you @cyberblitz. I'm glad you got there in the end! This has taken a lot of your time. Perhaps a re-think of the rendering would have allowed you to get there more quickly. Good luck with the rest of your project :-)

Comment: Thanks, but this problem is still not over, but I'm almost there thanks to you. So thank you